# What is minimum ios version for ionic?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I tried to add

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="6.0" />
```

in my config.xml and when I try to run it in xcode I get 
"Thread1: signal SIGABRT" in main.m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Cordova official docs:

```
The device must have at least iOS 8 installed,
```

Link: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/